# BigQuery couldn't connect to cloud SQL (MYSQL)

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connecto my bigquery instance to my db (mysql@5.7) hosted on Cloud SQL the issue that I have once that we changed the database on my externa connection we got the following error: Method not found or User or password are empty and I can't update user and password

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$ bq mk \
     --connection \
     --connection_type='CLOUD_SQL' \
     --properties='{"instanceId":"myproject:us-east1:mysqlinstance","database":"mydb","type":"MYSQL"}' \
     --connection_credential='{"username":"username", "password":"*****"}' \
     --project_id=myproject \
     --location=us \
     ext_cloud_sql
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("myproject.us.ext_cloud_sql", "SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;")
```

Comment: if you have used these options, please let me know, so that I will delete my post !

Comment: Thanks I can't give you and up because I don't have enough points

Answer (score 2):

There's a public tracker on this one and it seems the UI doesn't store the user credentials for the external connection.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/169526770

You can try creating the connection from the cloud shell (or any CLI), by using `bq mk` command or an example in this Google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#create_a_connection_resource%22)

Comment: Thanks I can't give you and up because I don't have enough points